# Timeout and out of memory errors reading large table using jdbc drivers

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

I am attempting to read a large table into a spark dataframe from an Oracle database using spark's native `read.jdbc` in scala. I have tested this with small and medium sized tables (up to 11M rows) and it works just fine. However, when attempting to bring in a larger table (~70M rows) I keep getting errors.

Sample code to show how I am reading this in:

```
val df = sparkSession.read.jdbc(
   url = jdbcUrl,
   table = "( SELECT * FROM keyspace.table WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM date_column) BETWEEN 2012 AND 2016)"
      columnName = "id_column", // numeric column, 40% NULL
      lowerBound = 1L,
      upperBound = 100000L,
      numPartitions = 60, // same as number of cores
      connectionProperties = connectionProperties) // this contains login & password
```

I am attempting to parallelise the operation, as I am using a cluster with 60 cores and 6 x 32GB RAM dedicated to this app. However, I still keep getting errors relating to timeouts and out of memory issues, such as:

```
17/08/16 14:01:18 WARN Executor: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
....

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds} 

...

17/08/16 14:17:14 ERROR RetryingBlockFetcher: Failed to fetch block rdd_2_89, and will not retry (0 retries)
    org.apache.spark.network.client.ChunkFetchFailureException: Failure while fetching StreamChunkId{streamId=398908024000, chunkIndex=0}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE
      at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:869)
      at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$4.apply(DiskStore.scala:125)
...


17/08/16 14:17:14 WARN BlockManager: Failed to fetch block after 1 fetch failures. Most recent failure cause:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
```

There should be more than enough RAM across the cluster for a table of this size (I've read in local tables 10x bigger), so I have a feeling that for some reason the data read may not be happening in parallel? Looking at the timeline in the spark UI, I can see that one executor hangs and is 'computing' for very long periods of time. Now, the partitioning column has a lot of NULL values in it (about 40%), but it is the only numeric column (other's are dates and strings) -  could this make a difference? Is there another way to parallelise a jdbc read?

Answer (score 0):

> the partitioning column has a lot of NULL values in it (about 40%), but it is the only numeric column (other's are dates and strings) - could this make a difference?

It makes a huge difference. All values with `NULL` [will go to the last partition](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3f958a99921d149fb9fdf7ba7e78957afdad1405/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCRelation.scala#L93):

```
val whereClause =
  if (uBound == null) {
    lBound
  } else if (lBound == null) {
    s"$uBound or $column is null"
  } else {
    s"$lBound AND $uBound"
}
```

> Is there another way to parallelise a jdbc read?

You can use `predicates` with other columns than numeric ones. You could for example use `ROWID` pseudocoulmn in `table` and use a series of predicates based on prefix.

Comment: OK, i just tried using a date column, that doesn't work (error: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER`). What exactly do you mean by 'a series of predicates based on prefix'? And do all SQL tables have a ROWID pseudocolumn? Apologies if these are n00b questions - I'm still pretty new to all this.